# How to export AWS-APIGateway Resource/method's name to Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, api-gateway

When export an api from APIGateway to Postman it export it like the image below.
the folder is the name of the resource and all of the methods are nameless.

the /list was added manually by me on Postman.

Tried:

1. Edit the resource/method documentation.
2. Add tags to the API gateway description json such "name" in different places.

My desired result is to get the option to add on API gateway some information so when I'll export the API to Postman I'll see that information on the method name part of Postman.

[image]